# Use Resources in MVCSiteMapProvider in actions, controllers... within the node definition

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider

I would like to use strings from resources to define the controllers and actions in my MVC.sitemap file, when it comes to use resources for the title there is no problem:

```
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:ResourcesTest,Testimonios" controller="Testimonios"  action="Index" />
```

But when i try to use resources as an the name of the action and controller it does not work:

```
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:ResourcesTest,Testimonios" controller="$resources:ControllersTests,Controller1Test"  action="Index" />
```

Is this a normal behaviour? I am doing something wrong? Is there any solution to my objective of using resources to define the action and controller names in the sitemap file?

Thanks¡¡

Comment: At the very least it seems like an odd use of Resources.

Comment: Hi dbaseman, the issue is that i am making a localization of a site into other language and I would like to have all the strings centralized in files as much as possible... doing that it would be only to change the names of the files. I know that there are some approaches but this is the one that seems quicklier and easier for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Controller property is not localizable.

Only the Title, Description, ImageUrl, and [custom attributes](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Using-Custom-Attributes-on-a-Node) are localizable properties.